# Complex parameter for startOfDay function in JIRA Query (JQL)

Tags: jira, jql

On JIRA, I would like to get issues created in the interval StartOfDay(-1M +1d) and startOdDay(-21d) but can't figure out how to properly write the "-1M +1d" parameter on the JQL

I try to write with different format but always get an error.
Also I tried to do something like startOfDay(-1M) + 1 but without better result

Can anyone help to find the good way of writing the query ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for *one month + one day* ago, the syntax would be "-1M 1d". I do not think you can specify *one month - one day* ago. The syntax is more like a representation of 4 hours, 35 minutes, and 20 seconds as 4:35:20  than a math formula.

I do not know your used case but perhaps consider a range of -29d to -21d. That would give you a consistent number of days in your search range.